# Microsoft .NET Error Message on Connecting Samsung Earbuds to Windows 11 via Bluetooth

Tags: windows, bluetooth

When ever I turn on Bluetooth and try to connect to my Samsung earbuds 2, I get the error message as shown in the screenshot. The device is shown as connected, but the audio does not play.
This problem is only on my PC having windows 11 and it works just fine on my friends PC also having windows 11.

Error message on connecting to Samsung Earbuds 2:
[image: error message on connecting to Samsung earbuds 2.png]

The details of the error message are as follows:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at QuickControls.Connection.PairedDeviceConnectionStatusWatcher.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<<ConnectionStatusChanged>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_0(Object state)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
System.Private.CoreLib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.55902
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Private.CoreLib.dll
----------------------------------------
QuickControls
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/QuickControls.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.800.122.30903
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 4.2.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.Specialized
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Collections.Specialized.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
----------------------------------------
Serilog
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.10.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Serilog.dll
----------------------------------------
netstandard
    Assembly Version: 2.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/netstandard.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Common
    Assembly Version: 4.0.2.3
    Win32 Version: 4.700.21.51508
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Drawing.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Threading.dll
----------------------------------------
Windows.Storage
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Storage.winmd
----------------------------------------
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Windows.Foundation
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Foundation.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
    Assembly Version: 4.0.4.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
----------------------------------------
Vanara.PInvoke.PowrProf
    Assembly Version: 3.4.13.0
    Win32 Version: 3.4.13.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Vanara.PInvoke.PowrProf.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.Registry
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.0.20.51904
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.TraceSource
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Collections.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.Debug
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Thread
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Threading.Thread.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.800.122.30903
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel
    Assembly Version: 4.0.4.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.ComponentModel.dll
----------------------------------------
Serilog.Sinks.Trace
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Serilog.Sinks.Trace.dll
----------------------------------------
Serilog.Sinks.File
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Serilog.Sinks.File.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Text.Encoding
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Text.Encoding.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Text.RegularExpressions
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.IO.FileSystem
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.IO.FileSystem.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Memory
    Assembly Version: 4.2.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Memory.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration
    Assembly Version: 4.1.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight
    Assembly Version: 4.1.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Reflection.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Private.Uri
    Assembly Version: 4.0.6.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Private.Uri.dll
----------------------------------------
Vanara.PInvoke.Shared
    Assembly Version: 3.4.13.0
    Win32 Version: 3.4.13.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Vanara.PInvoke.Shared.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Tasks
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Threading.Tasks.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ObjectModel
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.ObjectModel.dll
----------------------------------------
Windows.ApplicationModel
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.Concurrent
    Assembly Version: 4.0.15.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
----------------------------------------
Windows.Devices
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Devices.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
    Assembly Version: 4.0.15.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents
    Assembly Version: 4.0.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.19.56404
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Buffers
    Assembly Version: 4.0.5.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Buffers.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.NonGeneric
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.ThreadPool
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
----------------------------------------
Newtonsoft.Json
    Assembly Version: 13.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 13.0.3.27908
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters
    Assembly Version: 4.0.4.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Linq.Expressions
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Linq.Expressions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.Common
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Data.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.ReaderWriter
    Assembly Version: 4.2.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Private.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Private.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.55902
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Private.CoreLib.dll
----------------------------------------
SPPMessageParserLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/SPPMessageParserLib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.XamlHost
    Assembly Version: 6.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.1.2.13
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.XamlHost.dll
----------------------------------------
Windows.UI.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.UI
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.UI.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics.Vectors
    Assembly Version: 4.1.6.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.5.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Resources.ResourceManager
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.700.22.56512
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.Managed
    Assembly Version: 6.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.1.2.13
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/QuickControls/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.Managed.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.GalaxyBuds_4.8.0.0_x64__3c1yjt4zspk6g/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.winmd
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
```

Comment: So what's your question? This is a bug. Contact Samsung Support.

Comment: The question is obvious. Their support is not that helpful on the windows platform. Any other solutions for this problem are appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the galaxy buds app?

Comment: Yes, I have installed that app on windows, but I get this error even before I start the buds application

Comment: Have you tried to click "Continue"? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Uninstall the Samsung software. It shouldn’t be necessary to use your BT device. The software is automatically running more than likely but immediately crashes due to an unhandled exception

Comment: @Ramhound that solved the popup error message issue. Now Bluetooth shows it as connected, but as soon as I play an audio, it disconnects :(

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the tip! As I remember, it didn't have any effect, anyway I've deleted the software that caused this issue